Flashing underscore on boot
I've encountered a bit of a problem.
I have two discs:

First one is for Ubuntu
Second one for PearOS and Windows 10

The second disc is the one I'm having problems with.
Normally it would boot into a PearOS bootloader where I can select which OS I want to use. But after some stupid idea of converting this disc from MBR to GPT and back to MBR when it didn't work as intended, I couldn't boot into anything on this disc. I keep seeing a flashing underscore on startup, and I can't access the command line. My first drive with Ubuntu still works (MBR disc as well), but I really need Windows for office.
So does anyone know how I can solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

By converting the disk I would have expected it to render anything on it inaccessible. There may be tools that claim to be able to convert without data loss but I am pretty sure the regular command line tools don’t do that. I hope you have backups of any important data. The OSs can be reinstalled. If you need to do that use GPT

You've not provided Ubuntu product/release details; but have you tried asking Ubuntu to scan for other OSes and thus include them in its grub (ie. sudo update-grub).  Depending on your product/release which you gave no specifics; you may need to adjust it so it'll scan other drive/partitions (esp. if Ubuntu was installed with only one drive connected; upstream Grub changed defaults but Ubuntu is easier than most), but that's an easy edit if required for your unstated Ubuntu product/release (you may also not need it for some products/releases anyway).

This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
